# GWT - JSNI - passing json object

Tags: json, gwt, double-quotes, jsni

I have a json like below-

```
String sdata = "[{ name : "AAPL", data:[[1112832000000,43.56],[1112918400000,43.74],[1113177600000,41.92],[1113264000000,null],[1113350400000,null]], tooltip: {valueDecimals: 2}}]";
```

I am using JSNI to pass this from java to javascript.

```
public static native JavaScriptObject drawStock(Element element,String cname, String sdata) /*-{
       var chart = new $wnd.Highcharts.StockChart({
           chart : {
               renderTo : element
           },

           rangeSelector : {
               selected : 1
           },

           title : {
               text : cname
           },

           series : sdata    //=====this is where the json should be assigned.

           });

return chart;

}-*/;
```

The above native function does not work as expected because "i believe", the sdata variable has a double quotes around it and therefore is not thought of as a json object by javascript.

How can I pass the json object from java without the quotes to the javascript native interface function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the safeEval function to evaluate safely in java.

JavaScriptObject jsdata= JsonUtils.safeEval(sdata.toString());

drawStock(element,cname, jsdata);

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are assigning `series` to the **string** containing the JSON object, not the object itself.  To convert it into an object use `eval`:

```
series: eval(sdata)
```